# How to group by quarters(1 year = 4 quarters) in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Question Description**:Show for each customer and product combination, the average sales quantities for 4 quarters,Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q4(in four separate columns) –Q1 being the first 3 months of the year (Jan, Feb & Mar), Q2 the next 3 months (Apr, May & Jun), and so on–ignore the YEAR component of the dates (i.e., 3/11/2001is considered the same date as 3/11/2002, etc.).Also compute the average for the “whole” year(again ignoring the YEAR component, meaning simply compute AVG) along with the total quantities(SUM) and the counts(COUNT).

**table as follow**:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ga6QU.jpg)

**The sample result**:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81YCR.png)

I am a beginner on SQL and I met such a problem. It needs to group the 4 quarters just by using aggregate functions and group by clause.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Combination: you have to join the tables. Average: use the aggregate function and a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Please read the [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/102984).

Comment: @Laurenz Albe Thanks for your answer. In order to get the four quarters Average, which attribute should I group by? Can you please explain just more in detail? Thanks

Comment: @CL Sorry, but I don’t ask for answer or code.

Comment: You won't group by a column, but by an expression that yields the quarter you need. Look at the `date_trunc` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with cte as (
    select
        customer,
        product,
        case
            when (month < 4) then 'Q1'
            when (month >= 4 AND month < 7) then 'Q2'
            when (month >= 7 AND month < 10) then 'Q3'
            when (month >= 10) then 'Q4'
        end AS quarter,
        quant
    from bgg.table_sof
),
cte_full as (
        select
        customer,
        product,
        avg(quant) as average,
        sum(quant) as total,
        count(quant) as count
    from bgg.table_sof
    GROUP BY customer, product
)
select
       cte_full.customer,
       cte_full.product,
       avg(cte1.quant) as Q1_AVG,
       avg(cte2.quant) as Q2_AVG,
       avg(cte3.quant) as Q3_AVG,
       avg(cte4.quant) as Q4_AVG,
       average,
       total,
       count
from cte_full
left join cte cte1 on cte_full.customer = cte1.customer and cte_full.product = cte1.product
left join cte cte2 on cte_full.customer = cte2.customer and cte_full.product = cte2.product
left join cte cte3 on cte_full.customer = cte3.customer and cte_full.product = cte3.product
left join cte cte4 on cte_full.customer = cte4.customer and cte_full.product = cte4.product
where cte1.quarter = 'Q1' OR cte2.quarter = 'Q2' OR cte3.quarter = 'Q3' OR cte4.quarter = 'Q4'
group by cte_full.customer, cte_full.product, average, total, count;
```

It's a tricky task for a beginner. My advice is to start with some theory and easy practice.

There is two CTE (common table expression):
the first is for defining quarters from months. 
the second (cte_full) for calculating the last 3 columns in the result table.
And final select joins separately calculated avg by quarters to result.
I'm sure it isn't easy for understanding for beginner, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and I think it is clear. But if I only want to use aggregate functions and some basic syntaxes, that means I don't want use 'CASE' syntax. Then how can I achieve the answer.